# Apache Flink DataSet API: How to merge a Flink DataSet with itself to a new one?

Tags: java, dataset, apache-flink, bigdata

I have a single dimension DataSet of type String:

```
DataSet<String> x = //['dog','cat','sheep']
```

I want to compare all Strings with the other ones of this DataSet to analyse different string similarity algorithms. Therefore I need a resulting Dataset with the following Structure:

```
DataSet<Tuple2<String,String>> y = //[{'dog','cat'},{'dog','sheep'},{'cat','sheep'}]
```

On this DataSet a flatMap function (or similar) can be applied to compare the Strings.

My problem is that I don't know which Transformation I have to use. Maybe a Transformation is not the right way to handle that.

In plain Java I simple use two loops like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < x.length() ; i++){
    for(int j = i+1 ; i< x.length(); j++){
        //do something with x[i] and x[j]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x.cross(x) should do the trick. this will execute a default-cross.

Comment: Thanks for help! The cross transformation works. Im my case I use 1. x.cross(x) and 2. a filter transformation to filter out all not  neccessary tuples to build a strict upper triangular matrix (A=a[i][j]  and remove a[i][j] for i >= j ) .... If there is a more performant way let me know.